# Django DetailView is not working with additional parameter

Tags: django, url-pattern

Hi I am new to Django programming

please find my program which is not working.I am not getting any error though.

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'departmentlist/',views.DepartmentList.as_view(),name='departmentlist'),
    url(r'^departmentlist/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.DepartmentDetail.as_view(),name='departmentdetail'),
 ]
```

But when I am passing the `'(?P<pk>\d+)$'` alone it is working...Can any one help me.

Comment: actual urls,py is the following.                            url(r'departmentlist/',views.DepartmentList.as_view(),name='departmentlist'),
  url(r'^departmentlist/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.DepartmentDetail.as_view(),name='departmentdetail'),          after saving the question the <pk> was getting vanished

Answer (score 0):

You didn't terminate the pattern for the list view.

```
url(r'^departmentlist/$',views.DepartmentList.as_view(),name='departmentlist'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the URL to:

```
url(r'^departmentlist/(?P<pk>[\d+])$',views.DepartmentDetail.as_view(),name='departmentdetail'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.I could figure out the issue.I have written the rgx for departmentlist first so , it was comparing that first and got a match and stopped.so it did not go to the next comparison(departmentlist/<pk>).